# if there is an exception then stop and go to page load?

Tags: .net, vb.net

In the code below I have nested functions / subs

What is meant to happen is if there is an exception  then stop wherever the code is and add the exception to a global variable and go to the line below 'If there was an exception then go here'

How do I do this as my code below is not working? surely this has to be easy?

Below if the exception happens in Inner_B() then it gets caught in Inner_A() but I want tit caught in Inner_B()

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim textOutput As String = String.Empty
    Dim strErrorMesssage As String = String.Empty

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Outer()
        'If there was an exception then go here'
    End Sub


    Private Function Outer() As String
        Try
            Inner_A()
        Catch ex As Exception
            strErrorMesssage = ex.Message
            Throw
        End Try
        textOutput &= " Function Outer"
        Return " Function Outer"
    End Function


    Private Function Inner_A() As String
        Try
            Inner_B()
        Catch ex As Exception
            strErrorMesssage = ex.Message & " Inner_A() "
            Throw
        End Try

        textOutput &= " Function Inner_A"
        Return " Function Inner_A"
    End Function

    Private Sub Inner_B()
        Throw New ApplicationException("Exception Occured")
        Try
            Inner_C()
        Catch ex As Exception
            strErrorMesssage = ex.Message & " Inner_B() "
            Throw
        End Try
        textOutput &= " Sub Inner_B"
    End Sub

    Private Function Inner_C() As String
        Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            strErrorMesssage = ex.Message & " Inner_C() "
            Throw
        End Try
        textOutput &= " Function Inner_C"
        Return "Inner_C"
    End Function





End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing at what you mean by 'not working', but I assume you're not getting to execute code after the call to `Outer()`?

Just wrap it in a Try Catch as well but don't re-throw the exception if you want to conintue anyway.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Outer()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'do something with it here if you want, or not.
    End Try

    'Do more here.
 End Sub
```

Comment: and if I've guessed wrong, please don't downvote for that alone, I'll remove the answer if that's the case.

Comment: the first thing he is doing in innerB is throwing exception, of course it leaves innerb and nothing else happens there

Comment: Missed that -- hopefully it's just a remnant of testing "what happens when I throw an exception here"

Comment: Is that because its out side the try? thanks for the help every one

Comment: Yes.. throwing that exception in innerB, innerA will catch it, but innerB will not.